# Label conditions for multiple slave in declarative pipeline of Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use the below :

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'slave1 || slave2' }
stages{
}
}
```

When I am using the above format, the job is executing in slave1. But when I am reversing the format i.e
agent { label 'slave2 || slave1' }, its still executing on slave1.
Could you please help in clarifying is it the expected way of working. Isn't it something like the label written first, is given first precedence .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of Jenkins, not a bug. It tries to be consistent in choosing a slave, as this has a potential of saving some time. For example, on a slave that was used previously, the results of a checkout may still be in the workspace.

Since `slave1` fits both the requirements of `'slave1 || slave2'` and `'slave2 || slave1'`, Jenkins will use it. If it's unavailable or busy, some other slave will be used instead.